# Unique access to Kubernetes resources

Tags: kubernetes

For some integration tests we would like to have a way of ensuring, that only one test at a time has access to certain resources (e.g. 3 *DeploymentConfigurations*).

For that to work we have have the following workflow:

1. Before test is started - wait until all *DCs* are "undeployed".
2. When test is started - set *DC* `replicas` to `1`.
3. When test is stopped - set *DC* `replicas` to `0`.

This works to some degree, but obviously has the problem, that once the test terminates unexpectedly, the *DCs* might still be in flight.

Now one way to "solve" this would be to introduce a *CR*, with a *Controller*, which handles lifetime of the lock (CR).

Is there any more elegant and straight forward way of allowing unique access to Kubernetes resources?

---

**EDIT:**

Sadly we are stuck with Kubernetes 1.9 for now.

Answer (score 1):

look at 'kubectl wait' api to set different conditions between the test flow and depending on the result proceed to next test step.

Comment: Sounds great. Sadly we are still stuck with 1.9 :(